# Why is the variable on the y-axis of Maxwell's Speed Distribution Curve 'fraction of molecules'?

Tags: kinetics

I came across the following graph in my textbook showing the kinetic energy distribution of the gas molecules in a gas sample. Now, the thing is the textbook is telling that the area under the curve gives us the fraction of molecules with energy E. Suppose $dN_{E}$ represents the number of molecules with energy E, $N_{T}$ represents the total number of molecules and $E$ represents the kinetic energy of the molecules. Then, the fraction of molecules with energy $E$ is given by $\frac{dN_{E}}{N_{T}}$, right? So this actually represents the variable in the $y$-axis. Now, let us take the area of a small strip under the curve. It is given by $\frac{dN_{E}}{N_{T}} × dE$ which is clearly not equal to the fraction of molecules with energy $E$. Then why is the book telling that the area under the curve gives us the fraction of molecules with energy $E$? It clearly does not. I just proved it. If the area under the curve really has to represent the fraction of molecules with energy $E$ then instead of fraction of molecules i.e. $\frac{dN_{E}}{N_{T}}$ on the $y$-axis, the variable in the $y$-axis should actually be $\frac{1}{dE}\frac{dN_{E}}{N_{T}}$. Now if we calculate the area of a small strip under the curve :

$\frac{1}{dE}\frac{dN_{E}}{N_{T}} × dE = \frac{dN_{E}}{N_{T}}$

The quantity $\frac{dN_{E}}{N_{T}}$ actually gives the fraction of molecules with energy $E$. Thus, my book is wrong, isn't it? Please can someone clarify if what I have done is correct or not. Can someone explain?

[image: Maxwell Speed Distribution Curve]

Comment: y represents the fraction *density*.  y . dE represents the fraction dN/N. Integral E0 to infinity of y.dE then represents fraction E>E0.  y cannot be 1/dE . dN/N, as the bottom dE does not follow the upper dE.

Comment: Please elaborate.

Comment: What part do you not understand ?

Comment: Is the variable in the y-axis $\frac{1}{dE}\frac{dN_{E}}{N_{T}}$ or is it $\frac{dN_{E}}{N_{T}}$ or is it something else?

Comment: The function on the graph is not the fraction, but the fraction density. The fraction is get by multiplying by dE, or integrating over E interval. So the former, but rearranged, as it is formally wrong. It is derivative of the cumulative function f(E)=N(E_mol<=E)/N_T. . Your original expression (1/dE).(dN/N).dE creates false impression both dE are the same, mutually clearable differentials.

Comment: The graph is drawn between 'fraction of molecules' and 'kinetic energy'. My final question is what exactly is 'fraction of molecules'? Can you please write 'fraction of molecules' in mathematical form? (For example, in the graph between speed and time, speed in mathematical form can be written as $\frac{dx}{dt}$ and time is $t$. So, graph is actually being drawn between $\frac{dx}{dt}$ and $t$). In this way, could you tell me what 'fraction of molecules' and 'kinetic energy' mean in mathematical form? Can you represent them in terms of variables like I did with speed and time?(Please help me)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123379/discussion-between-poutnik-and-pranita-baruah-1).